# What might be the error in this line of code in R

Tags: r

This is the line with the error:

`predicted <-predict(fit, test_data`)

This is the code for testing the model for predicting the income

The error that I got was:

> Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action,
> xlev = object$xlevels) :    factor education has new levels 10th,
> 11th, 12th, 1st-4th, 5th-6th, 7th-8th, 9th, Assoc-acdm, Assoc-voc,
> Bachelors, Doctorate, HS-grad, Masters, Preschool, Prof-school,
> Some-college

Comment: looks like you trained your model with a certain set of levels for education, and that the new data has new levels it didn't see by training : provide training data with all possible levels if you want the model to make predictions.

Comment: To this point, it may be helpful if you share `str(df)` for your training model and the `test_data`.

Comment: don't worry, I got the solution and answered below.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

Just needed to factorize the education column

```
train_data$education = factor(train_data$education)
```